# How get list who am I sponsoring

Tags: youtube-data-api

*hi, sry for the mistakes, I'm just using google translator*

So, can I view through oauth whether I have subscribed to the channel and sponsor it?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, Unfortunately, This question is a little bit too vague, it asks very generally for what would constitute a tutorial instead of asking a specific question. Therefore it is not suitable for stackoverflow as Stackoverflow is not a tutorial provider or a free code writing service, I recommend new users to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on asking questions that are well-suited for the site and best enable the community to provide helpful feedback.